# iOS Multiline Label NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a label with `numberOfLines` set to 2, `lineBreakMode` set to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`. I was expecting that when the text extends beyond two lines, the label will truncate it with ellipses. But what is happening is that although the text is being truncated no ellipses are getting shown.

Why would this be? Thanks.

More details:
Following is the custom class for the UITableViewCell that contains the label (`contentLabel`) in question. The labels are updated in the `loadConversation` method.

```
@interface CPActivityStreamCell ()
@property(nonatomic, weak) CardDeck *cardDeck;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *icon;
@end

@implementation CPActivityStreamCell

@synthesize contentLabel, eventLabel, avatarView;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Initialize views
    [contentLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    [contentLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [contentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1.0]];
    contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [eventLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    [eventLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [eventLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [eventLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1.0]];
    eventLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    eventLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Antonio-Regular" size:12];

    // Create the icon view
    UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 15.0, 16.0, 16.0)];
    [self addSubview:icon];
    self.icon = icon;

    CardDeck *deck = [[CardDeck alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.frame numberOfCards:1];
    self.backgroundView = deck;
    self.cardDeck = deck;
}

- (void)loadConversation:(CPConversation *)conversation {
    [self loadAvatars:conversation.avatarUrls];
    self.contentLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.eventLabel.text = [conversation.eventTitle uppercaseString];
    self.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1.0];
    self.contentLabel.text = conversation.content;
    [self loadEventTypeIcon:conversation.eventType white:NO];
    [self updateDeck:conversation withFrame:self.contentView.frame];
    if ([conversation.typeString isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        [self loadConversationImage:conversation];
    }
}

//other methods

@end
```

The same label in IB:

[image]

Output:
The top cell's contentLabel is set to `Start of a really long text to test truncation and display in activity stream. It should be truncated with ellipses. End.`:

[image]

Comment: It should work, but only if you are setting the label's `text`. If you are setting the `attributedText`, all bets are off. Could you give more details of this label's configuration? Thx.

Comment: can you check the linbreakMode of your lable by debugging the live object also check the frame of your lable.

Comment: I debugged and the debug shows label's numberOfLines property as 2 and lineBreakMode as 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies somewhere in the architecture of your initialization procedure, or possibly in something you are doing elsewhere (in code you have not shown in your question). You are saying

```
[contentLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[contentLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[contentLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[contentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1.0]];
contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But this code is not being applied to the label we see in the screen shot. That much is clear, because if it *were* being applied, the text would be a light gray color.

Thus we may conclude that this code is not running or, if it is running, `contentLabel` is not hooked up property (perhaps it is nil) and the label is unaffected by it.

Finally, I may point out that on my machine I simply ran your code as given, directly, on a UILabel (not in a table view or anything), and it worked:

```
[contentLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[contentLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
[contentLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[contentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1.0]];
contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
contentLabel.text = @"Start of a really long text to test truncation and display in activity stream. It should be truncated with ellipses. End.";
```

[image]

Thus I suggest that either your code is not running or not being applied to the label, or that some other code is coming along and changing the line break mode for this label. It is always best to convince oneself that something works *generally* for an extremely simple case (like mine, in the preceding code) and then try to figure out why *particular* results seem to differ from that...

Comment: About the color. The color is reset in loadConversation method to black. When the conversation has an image it is set to white. The code is messy and I am in the process of cleaning it up.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that; I finally noticed that about the color.

Comment: Still, I have proved to you that this can work correctly, by showing you code and a screen shot. So now you have to figure out why this is not happening for the labels that you see in your app.

Comment: It was a bug in my code :(. conversation.content was being truncated to 75 characters in CPConversation class's implementation.

Comment: Well done! And note the technique we used here: by doing the same thing completely out of the context of your app, we _proved_ that there must be other code somewhere that was making the difference, because otherwise it _would_ have worked as expected. I often resort to this trick when I'm stuck: make a mini-project to test how things work in isolation, outside the complexity of the real app.